# TypeError: req.logIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, discord, passport.js

I'm making a dashboard for my discord bot, but im getting this error:

```
TypeError: req.logIn is not a function
    at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\joasb\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:247:13)
    at verified (C:\Users\joasb\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:189:20)
    at Strategy._verify (C:\Users\joasb\Desktop\Bot\strategies\discord.js:38:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

These are my files:
app.js:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
require('./strategies/discord');

const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const routes = require('./routes');

mongoose.connect(`${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use('/api', routes); 
app.use(passport.initialize());   
app.use(passport.session());

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Running on port ${PORT}`));
```

And discord.js

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const DiscordStrategy = require('passport-discord');
const UserDB = require('../database/Schemas/UserDB');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.discordId)
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (user, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await UserDB.findOne({ discordId });
        return user ? done(null, user) : done(null, null);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        done(err, null);
    }
});


passport.use(
    
    new DiscordStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.DASHBOARD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.DASHBOARD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.DASHBOARD_CALLBACK_URL,
        scope: ['identify', 'guilds'],
    }, async (accesToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        try {
            const { id, username, discriminator, avatar, guilds } = profile;
            console.log(id, username, discriminator, avatar, guilds);
            const findUser = await UserDB.findOne({ discordId: id }, {
                discordTag: `${username}#${discriminator}`,
                avatar,
                guilds: guilds.length,
            });
            if (findUser) {
                console.log(`User was found!`);
                return done(null, findUser);
            } else {
                const newUser = await UserDB.create({
                    discordId: id,
                    discordTag: `${username}#${discriminator}`,
                    avatar,
                    guilds: guilds.length,
                });
                return done(null, newUser);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    })
);
```

I also have a couple of strategies, but those are not the problem as they work just fine. I can authorize my client but after that it just gives the error and crashes.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
satvik choudhary asked me to add the package.json so here it is:

```js
{
  "name": "quabot-db",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.14",
    "passport": "^0.5.0",
    "passport-discord": "^0.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that others have faced this issue before. Checkout https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues?q=is%3Aissue+req.login

Comment: The issues there dont fix my issue

Comment: add your package.json to the question.

Comment: It's there now.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your middleware is wrong. You initialize passport *after* handling any API routes, so when you call `req.logIn` in your route, it doesn't even exist yet!

It should be the other way round:

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());   
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/api', routes);
```